# Alternative to null check after DOM traversal?

Tags: javascript, tree, dom, null

I have this code working, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to write it. I was watching a JS talk on Maintainable JavaScript, and saw that I probably shouldn't be comparing my element  to null, and instead should use `typeof`. However, regardless what is returned, it's still an object.

What my code does:

So I needed this code to determine which top-level nav the sub-menu navigations correspond too. What this example does is finds a submenu nav item and grabs it's inner text, then it gets thrown into a while loop to traverse the DOM to find the top-level nav's innerText so I can then have both a *top-level nav name* and *sub-menu nav name*. However if the top-level nav does not have a sub-menu then it returns nothing.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('gtm_navHeader')[25];
var elementText = element.innerText
var elementClass = "menu-parent";

while(element && !((" " + element.className + " ").indexOf(" " + elementClass + " ") > -1)){
    element = element.parentNode;
}

  if (element == null){
    console.log('equals null - ' + elementText);
  }else{
    var anchor = element.querySelector("a");
    var clean = (anchor.innerText || anchor.textContent).toLowerCase() + " : " + elementText;
    console.log('does not equal - ' + clean);
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x9r65/)**

Let me know if you have any questions. Happy to provide more information.

Comment: I imagine the `[25]` is just an example index, right? You're not hard-coding that in your site's code, are you?

Comment: @Flambino, yes, correct.

Comment: I wonder when will `(element == null)` will return true! If not found it will return `undefined`

Comment: @VivekParekh and `null == undefined`

Comment: @Blexy `foo == null` is equivalent to `!foo`; that would be the more common way to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stuff I noticed:

You're missing a semi-colon:

```
var elementText = element.innerText
```

The `elementClass` variable could have a slightly more descriptive variable name. "targetClass" for instance, to indicate that this is the class we're going to look for.

This loop condition is overly complicated:

```
while(element && !((" " + element.className + " ").indexOf(" " + elementClass + " ") > -1)){
```

Your code says "if x is *not* greater than -1", which is the same as simply saying "if x *is* -1", i.e. `x == -1` (or better yet, strict equality: `x === -1`), so that would clean things up.

Also, instead of all the string-concatenation, you could:

1. Use `element.classList.contains('menu-parent')` if you're targeting modern browsers (Internet Explorer 9 and below [don't support `classList`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist))
2. Or use `element.className.split(' ').indexOf(...)` to look through an array of discrete class names (basically emulating `classList`)
3. Or use a regular expression like `/(^|\s)menu-parent(\s|$)/i.test(element.className)`
4. Or add the spaces in the `elementClass` variable, so you don't have to add them every time you want to check.

I'd use #2. This gets us:

```
while(element && element.className.indexOf(elementClass) === -1) {
```

More on this later.

Then there's this:

```
  if (element == null){
    console.log('equals null - ' + elementText);
  }else{
    var anchor = element.querySelector("a");
    var clean = (anchor.innerText || anchor.textContent).toLowerCase() + " : " + elementText;
    console.log('does not equal - ' + clean);
}
```

For one, the indentation's wrong. For another, as you yourself wrote, you don't need the `== null` in the condition.
In fact, you've already used the plain `element` in the `while` loop's condition. There you checked if `element` "was anything" which is exactly the same thing you're doing here.

Also, don't leave `console.log` statements in your production code. Like the `25`, this is probably just a test-thing, right? Still, it's good to know that some JS runtimes don't have a console, so calling `console.log` will just cry "console is undefined!" and stop everything.

If you insist on using it, at least check whether `console` exists first:

```
if(console) { console.log(...); }
```

You could also throw that into a function, so you're sure to always have a check, and so you have 1 place in which to simply turn off logging.

Now, getting back to the loop: I'd change it up, making the "find ancestor by class name" a function:

```
function getAncestorByClassName(from, className) {
  while(from) {
    if(from.className.split(' ').indexOf(className) !== -1) { # or any of the other options
      return from; // found a match, return it (stops the loop, exits the function)
    }
    from = from.parentNode; // go up a level and repeat
  }
  return null; // if the loop just ended normally, we didn't find anything
}
```

Now we've got a generic function you can use whenever necessary. This makes the rest of the code a lot simpler:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('gtm_navHeader')[25],
    ancestor = getAncestorByClassName(element, 'menu-parent'),
    anchor, clean; // declare all your variables up top; just good practice

if(ancestor) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wow. I can't thank you enough for the recommendations. A few comments: I used className over classList due to old browser support - like you noted. Yes, console.log was just for testing, but I like the idea of checking whether console exists first. I'm going to look through this closer this weekend, so I may have questions, but I really appreciate the detailed answer. Cheers

Comment: @Blexy No problem. If you have further questions, however, make sure you post a new question (and maybe link back to this one if related). Don't update your current one, or existing answers lose their context.